# What advantages does Blender Render have?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

What advantages does Blender Render have? I personally always use Cycles Render, because I think the rendered material looks more realistic and node shaders are easier to use.

Comment: Cycles is more advanced and realistic. BI is simpler to use, if you don't require much realism and need a quick material setup. Also, I've once asked a question where I was getting noisy results in Cycles, but plausible and good-looking ones in BI https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31088/noise-reduction-in-tight-area-in-cycles

Comment: Cycles is not really Animation Ready as of yet, that is, despite it being far easier to create physically accurate photorealistic scenes compared with BI, the far greater render times for larger scenes don't lend themselves well to animation, or are less desirable. BI is also based on a scanline rendering method, and ends when the render finishes. Cycles however is based on a progressive rendering method, and gradually gets less noisy overtime, stopping when the user tells it to. :)